# Quick question about max heap

Tags: heaps

Suppose that we have a max heap and that it contains duplicate values .Is it always true that nodes with same value are adjacent(neighbors)?I think it is true because if there was any other node being intercepted between them then this would break the max heap property as it would be out of order(with respect to value) with at least one of the two nodes.
Is this correct?

Comment: Try $[3, 6, 6 ]$.

Comment: Yeah no need to intercept anything,it was that simple damn how i missed it.Thanks,appreciate your reply.